# React + Sails + Socket.io

Tags: sockets, reactjs, socket.io, sails.js

This is quite a broad question, however I currently have a Sails API server and a React Front-end (Standalone).

**Note: The React Front-End is NOT part of Sails**

I'm trying to get to grips with sockets, so I figured I would start simple.  I want to achieve the following:

- User visits my website (React)
- React opens a socket and connects to Sails
- Sails streams the data from within a function/model
- React updates when new data is added to the model

I semi understand how this works using Express and React, however I cannot get my head around how Sails implements their version of WebSockets on top of Sockets.io.

What I've done is install the sockets.io-client within React, and then trying to use sails.sockets inside Sails.

This is what I currently have:

**React Component** NB: I don't think this is correct at all

```
componentDidMount =()=> {
  this.getSessionData();
  UserStore.listen(this.getSessionData);
  Socket.emit('/listSessions', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

**Sails Function (listSessions)**

```
listSessions: function(req, res) {
    Session.find({ where: {visible: true},  sort: 'createdAt DESC'},
    function(err, sessions){

        if(req.isSocket){
            Session.watch(req.socket);
            console.log('User subscribed to ' + req.socket.id);
        }

        if(err) return res.json(500, {
            error: err,
            message: 'Something went wrong when finding trades'
        });

        return res.json(200, {
            sessions: sessions,
        });
    })
},
```

**Sails Function (createSession)**  Trying to use publishCreate to use in conjunction with Session.watch in the above function

```
createSession: function(req, res){

    var token = jwt.sign({
        expiresIn: 30,
    }, 'overwatch');


    Session.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        platform: req.body.platform,
        lookingFor: req.body.lookingFor,
        microphone: req.body.microphone,
        gameMode: req.body.gameMode,
        comments: req.body.comments,
        avatar: null,
        level: null,
        hash: token,
        competitiveRank: null,
        region: req.body.region,
        visible: true,
    }).exec(function(err, created){

        Session.publishCreate(created);

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send({
                error: err,
                message: 'Something went wrong when adding a session',
                code: 91
            })
        }
        if(req.isSocket){
            Session.watch(req.socket);
            console.log('User subscribed to ' + req.socket.id);
        }
        return res.send({
            session: created,
            code: 00,
        })
    });
},
```

Both of the Sails functions are called using POST/GET. 
I'm completely stumped as where to go with this, and it seems to documentation or explanation on how to get this working is limited.  All the Sails documentation on Sockets seems to relate to using Sails as a front-end and server

Comment: I can probably give out a more fleshed out answer later, but you have an easy to spot mixup. in your client you're passing a callback function to `socket.emit`. this is incorrect. When you EMIT you pass data (or null or whatever). When you want to receive data it's an ON handler `socket.on('someServerEvent', function (data) ...`

Comment: Thanks, however what I was trying to do their was to execute the post on the listSession function in Sails

Comment: Right, well that's not how that works. Even though sails might contain some built in socket stuff for you, there's nothing stopping you from adding the socket.io server side package and listen to events there, passing along any model data you need. Sockets are event based on named events which are different than routes used for HTTP calls.

Comment: Yeah I had figured that wasn't how it works, however I am stuck on even figuring out how to get a Sails function to send data to a connection.  According to the docs, publishCreate and Watch work together, but as you can see in my code, I need to get the initial data to React first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so I managed to solve this:

Simply put:

Within React, I had to include https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/tree/master

Then within my React component I did:

```
  componentDidMount =()=> {
    io.socket.get('/listSessions',(resData, jwres) => {
      console.log('test');
      this.setState({
        sessions: resData.sessions,
        loaded: true,
      })
    })

    io.socket.on('session', (event) => {
      if(event.verb == 'created') {

        let sessions = this.state.sessions;
        sessions.push(event.data);
        this.setState({
          sessions: sessions
        })
      } else {
        console.log('nah');
      }
    });
  }
```

This makes a virtual get request to Sails using Socket.io, and sets the response in state.  It also watches for updates to the 'session' connection and updates the state with these updates meaning I can update a list in real time

Within my Sails controller I have:

```
listSessions: function(req, res) {

    if(req.isSocket){
        Session.find({ where: {visible: true},  sort: 'createdAt DESC'},
        function(err, sessions){

            Session.watch(req.socket);

            if(err) return res.json(500, {
                error: err,
                message: 'Something went wrong when finding trades'
            });

            return res.json(200, {
                sessions: sessions,
            });
        })
    }
},
```

The Session.watch line listens for updates via publishCreate on the model which is found in my model as follows:

```
  afterCreate: function(message, next) {
    Session.publishCreate(message);
     next();
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answer by @K20GH , add the following to my "index.js" in React to help get sails.io.js from the CDN :

```
const fetchJsFromCDN = (src, externals = []) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        resolve(
            externals.map(key => {
                const ext = window[key];
                typeof ext === 'undefined' &&
                    console.warn(`No external named '${key}' in window`);
                return ext;
            })
        );
    });
    script.addEventListener('error', reject);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
};
fetchJsFromCDN(
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sails.io.js/1.0.1/sails.io.min.js',
    ['io']
).then(([io]) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
    }
});
```

Once you have this, you'll be able to use the HTTP type GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods. So here you can do:

```
componentDidMount =()=> {
io.socket.get('/listSessions',(resData, jwres) => {
  console.log('test');
  this.setState({
    sessions: resData.sessions,
    loaded: true,
  })
})

io.socket.on('session', (event) => {
  if(event.verb == 'created') {

    let sessions = this.state.sessions;
    sessions.push(event.data);
    this.setState({
      sessions: sessions
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Not created session');
  }
});
```

}

And you can do the required setup in sails for the models of sessions as suggested above